# How to implement CSS into Wicket 9.8.0

Tags: java, wicket

Despite using the `<wicket:link>` tags around my `<link>` tags my CSS is still not being applied to my HTML even with some attempts to move the css file into my webapp folder (Currently its in the same package as my wicket files).

My current HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <wicket:link>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    </wicket:link>
</head>
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" style="background-color: rgb(36, 0, 72);">

</header>
<body>
<div>

</div>
<span wicket:id="welcome">WELCOME</span>
<h1>testing</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

My Current CSS file (simple just for testing):

```
h1 {
    font-size: 100px;
}
.site-header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 30px;
    z-index: 10002;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    height: 95px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<wicket:link>` helps to construct a correct url to `style.css` when it is in the classpath, next to MyPage.html file. I.e. if `style.css` is in src/main/resources/com/example/pages folder and `MyPage.java` is in `com.example.pages`  package.

Usually CSS files are put in `src/main/webapp` folder. In this case you don't need to wrap it with `<wicket:link>`. You can read more about it in the [user guide](https://nightlies.apache.org/wicket/guide/9.x/single.html#_automatically_creating_bookmarkable_links_with_tag_wicket_link).

The best way to start with Wicket is by using the [quickstart application](https://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html)!

Comment: Even with my style sheet in `src/main/webapp` and not using the `<wicket:link>` tag my css is still not being applied. I have looked at the quickstart and the file placement and html matches.  Could it be something to do with Tomcat?

Comment: I doubt it is Tomcat. Does the quickstart app work in same Tomcat ?